# How to enable Expect-Ct on apache using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, security

i want to enable Expect-Ct on my website.
From searching around i creaded code on my own from searches.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Expect-CT: max-age=86400, enforce, report-uri="https://foo.example/report"
</IfModule>
```

I want to ask if this is right or not and what is report uri ? it can be any random link or something else.
for example my website is testwebsite.com then report uri should be testwebsite.com/report ? and how can i check reports ?

Comment: [This](https://scotthelme.co.uk/a-new-security-header-expect-ct/) might help.

Comment: i know that but i want to know if code is right for htaccess coz there is nothing like that , i have amde on my own.

Answer (score 7):

This is a good question; while the *general* syntax form is explained in the [link provided in comments](https://scotthelme.co.uk/a-new-security-header-expect-ct/), it doesn't explain how to correctly apply this header in the `.htaccess` or `httpd.conf`  Apache files.

Through trial and error I found this works:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Expect-CT enforce,max-age=2592000,report-uri="https://foo.example/report"
</IfModule>
```

Note that there should not be any white space in the "data" part.

Also note that the *output* detected by such things as [`redbot.org`](https://redbot.org) does not show exactly the same thing.